Order vector by vector with non-unique list and then alphabetically
Assume two vectors
a <- c("AA", "BA", "BB", "AB", "AC", "BC")
b <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)

I would like to order a by b, but obviously there exist a lot of possibilities as b has non-unique elements. So, my my further constraint is an alphabetical order to get
c("AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "AA", "BC")

is that possible?

a[order(b,a)].
